# Как вывести в текстбокс List<string> - результат асинхронного запроса?

Tags: c#, ping

Если делать в консоли - нормально работает (код 1), а если для формы (код 2, 3) - не выводит. Что тут делать?

```
       public static void PingMethod()
    {
        var urles = new List<string> ( Properties.Resources.proxylist.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) );

        var goodUrls = new List<string>();
        var badUrls = new List<string>();
        var timeout = 1;
        var sync = new object();
        var counter = urles.Count;
        var isReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        foreach (var ur in urles)
        {
            var _url = ur.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var u = _url[0];

            var url = u;
            var ping = new Ping();
            ping.PingCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                lock (sync)
                {
                    ping.Dispose();
                    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        goodUrls.Add(ur);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        badUrls.Add(url);
                    }
                    if (--counter == 0)
                    {
                        isReady.Set();
                    }
                }
            };
            ping.SendAsync(u, timeout, null);
        }
        isReady.WaitOne();

        Console.WriteLine("Good Urls");

        foreach (var u in goodUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(u);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Bad Urls");
        foreach (var u in badUrls)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(u);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("goodUrls " + goodUrls.Count);
        Console.WriteLine("badUrls " + badUrls.Count);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Для форм аналогичный метод:

```
        public static List<string> PingTwoMethod()
    {
        List<string> urles = new List<string>(Properties.Resources.proxylist_at_15_10_2015.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        List<string> goodUrls = new List<string>();
        List<string> badUrls = new List<string>();
        int timeout = 1;
        Object sync = new object();
        int counter = urles.Count;
        ManualResetEvent isReady = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        foreach (var ur in urles)
        {
            string[] _url = ur.Split(new string[] { ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            string u = _url[0];

            string url = u;
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            ping.PingCompleted += (s, e) =>
            {
                lock (sync)
                {
                    ping.Dispose();
                    if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    {
                        goodUrls.Add(url);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        badUrls.Add(url);
                    }
                    if (--counter == 0)
                    {
                        isReady.Set();
                    }                        
                }
            };
            ping.SendAsync(url, timeout, null);
            List<string> good = new List<string>(goodUrls);
            return good;
        }
        //isReady.WaitOne();
        return goodUrls;
    }
```

и кнопка на форме:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> goods = new List<string>();
        goods = Pings.PingMethod();            

        if (goods != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in goods)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text += item;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += "Пусто";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не пользуйтесь устаревшим API. Работайте через `Task`, многопоточные проблемы уйдут сами собой.

Например, так:

```
public async static Task<List<string>> Ping(List<string> ips)
{
    List<string> goodIps = new List<string>();
    List<string> badIps = new List<string>();
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    foreach (var ipAndPort in ips)
    {
        var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
        var answer = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
        if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            goodIps.Add(ipAndPort);
        else
            badIps.Add(ipAndPort);
    }
    return goodIps;
}
```

И код стал гораздо понятнее.

Если мы хотим пинговать всё *одновременно*, делаем так:

```
public async static Task<List<string>> Ping(List<string> ips)
{
    List<string> goodIps = new List<string>();
    List<string> badIps = new List<string>();
    Ping ping = new Ping();
    var tasks = ips.Select(ipAndPort =>
        {
            var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
            return ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
        }).ToList();
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    foreach (var answer in results)
    {
        if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            goodIps.Add(ipAndPort);
        else
            badIps.Add(ipAndPort);
    }
    return goodIps;
}
```

Вызывать теперь просто:

```
var allIps = ...;
var goodIps = await Ping(allIps);
if (goodIps.Count == 0)
    richTextBox.Text = "Все плохие";
else
    richTextBox.Text = string.Join("\n", goodIps);
```

Comment: не компилируется ваш код, вот так исправленный компилируется:

Comment: @pontekorvo: Вполне возможно, писал на коленке.

Comment: спасибо за быстрый ответ, 
первую исправил:
public async static Task<List<string>> Ping(List<string> ips)
и эту:
if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
и последнюю еще,
но т.к. тип выхода изменился, теперь непонятно как на экран вывести. Про этот Task<List<string>>  ничего найти не могу.

Comment: @pontekorvo: Окей, внёс исправления в текст ответа. Тип выхода по сути не изменился, может быть, вы забыли `await`? Покажите вызывающий код.

Comment: что-то не так с этим кодом - только одну итерацию в foreach() проходит.

Comment: @pontekorvo: А какого размера список вы передаёте в качестве параметра?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30414/discussion-between-pontekorvo-and-vladd).

Comment: @pontekorvo: Обновил ответ, тестируйте.

Comment: VladD - Спасибо за ваш пример ,нашёл для себя нужную строчку кода =)
закину вас в закладки - на будущее =)

Answer (score 0):

Пример VladD работает вот в таком виде, но - медленнее, чем предложенный в вопросе.

```
public async static Task<List<string>> Ping(List<string> ips)
    {
        List<string> goodIps = new List<string>();
        List<string> badIps = new List<string>();
        var timeout = 1;
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        foreach (var ipAndPort in ips)
        {
            var ip = ipAndPort.Split(':')[0];
            var answer = await ping.SendPingAsync(ip, timeout);
            if (answer.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                goodIps.Add(ipAndPort);
            else
                badIps.Add(ipAndPort);
        }
        return goodIps;
    }


        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Example();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static async void Example()
    {
        var allIps = new List<string>(Properties.Resources.proxylist.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
        var goodIps = await PingThree.Ping(allIps);

        if (goodIps.Count == 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Все плохие");
        else
            foreach (var item in goodIps)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
    }
```